# Are API key, Client ID, and/or Signature changes required to Upgrade Google Static Map Version

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I need to know if an instance of an Google Static Map API Key, Client ID and/or Signature is tied to a given API Version. If I have been using API V1 (Static Maps) and wish to now use API V2 do I need a new key, Client ID and/or Signature? I make this request from inside java code via a HttpURLConnection.

My current request for V1 is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=25.78939485541877,-80.2033928757234&size=1294x430&zoom=17&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false&format=png&client=***{my gme-* client id}***&signature=***{my signature}***
```

My new request for V2 is

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=25.78939485541877,-80.2033928757234&size=1294x430&zoom=17&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false&format=png&client=***{my gme-* client id}***&signature=***{my signature}***
```

Answer (score 0):

I was told on another forum that The API Key, Client ID and/or Signature are NOT tied to a given API version.

Also, it turns out both hosts listed in the question will go to API V2.  Google incorrectly informed us we were hitting the API V1 host, they sent us a email latter notifying us of there mistake.